# How can I add a line of code to an existing python's function

Tags: python

I've been reading recently about properties (i.e. `property` decorator), and I've come to the conclusion that I don't really like the way it's implemented in python. Well, I know it's not an internal part of the language itself (it's not built into the language like in C# for example), but I really think they could have implemented it better (even only with decorators). I wanted to make a proof-of-concept for the way I think it should have been implemented, and I have a little obstacle (nothing that can't be overcome though...).

Here is what I was thinking:
Say we a have a `Person` class, with a property `name`. My way of defining the property would look like:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age

    @my_property
    def name(self):
        def getter(self):
            return self._name

        def setter(self, value):
            self._name = value

        def deleter(self):
             del self._name

        return getter, setter, deleter
```

And we have the decorator `my_property` defined as follows:

```
def my_property(f):
    d = {g.__name__: g for g in f(None)}
    p = property(d.get('getter'), d.get('setter'), d.get('deleter'))
    return p
```

Now, this works great, but I really would like to improve it by allowing the user to not explicitly add the line of code:
`return getter, setter, deleter`. I want, instead, that the decorator will add that line to the function `f` passed to it (in our case, the `name` method). I guess I'll have to play around with the code object of `f` (i.e. `f.__code__`), but I can't figure out how to accomplish what I want.

My way of how properties should look like is very similar to the C# syntax for properties. I believe the getter, setter and deleter of the same field should be grouped together inside some block of code (in my case I chose a function definition), and not be spread around all over the class in (up to) 3 seperate methods (even if they have the same name, they're still separated syntactically)... Further more, I think the way it's defined right now - by first declaring the getter as a property by the `property` decorator, and then use the getter's name to decorate the setter and deleter is pretty much ugly. But that just me :)

***UPDATE***

After accepting the answer of *@User*, I re-implemented my property decorator, using his idea of getting the code objects from inside the wrapper method's code object. Here is my new implementation, which is still just a prototype (I believe it can be further improved).  I decided to shadow the builtin `property` decorator with my new decorator (which makes use of the original `property` decorator), but it can be called whatever you want... Overall, I think it's pretty cool, and I wish Python had a `property` keyword to be used to define properties, instead of using method definitions or classes definition (as suggested by **@User** in his answer).

```
def property(f, property=property):
    from types import CodeType, FunctionType
    d = {code.co_name: FunctionType(code, f.__globals__)
         for code in f.__code__.co_consts
         if type(code) is CodeType}
    return property(d.get('getter'), d.get('setter'), d.get('deleter'), f.__doc__)


class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age

    @property
    def name():
        def getter(self):
            return self._name
        def setter(self, value):
            self._name = value
        def deleter(self):
            del self._name

>>> p1 = Person('Name', 25)
>>> p1.name
'Name'
>>> p1.name = "New Name"
>>> p1.name
'New Name'
```

Comment: The direct answer to the question in your title is: Use your keyboard.

Comment: So you take issue with the fact that you have to use `@property`, `@x.setter`, and `@x.deleter`? Is that it?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Not sure if you were being sarcastic, or if you were serious... but anyway, maybe I should have added "dynamically" or "at run-time" to the title. As for your other comment, it's not the multiple use of decorators that's bothering me.. it's just that I find it ugly (or non-pretty) and I think it may be confusing when the class has a lot of methods and properties mixing with each other.

Comment: The correct title for your question would have been something like "how do I extend the @property decorator"? It took me a while to figure out what you were really trying to do because my choices for interpretation were a useless title or a wall of text.

Comment: Well, you're correct that the title doesn't say much about the content, but I think the content's structure is pretty straight forward - it has a little introduction, an example and a bottom line. Yeah, it may be a bit long for some, but I like to give as much information as possible. It's a fact that I got a really good answer in only a few minutes, and no other incorrect answers/comments thinking I meant something else. But thanks for reading anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you can make it prettier:

```
>>> def dec(f):
    import types
    codes = []
    for code in f.__code__.co_consts:
        if isinstance(code, types.CodeType):
            codes.append(code)
    getter = types.FunctionType(codes[0], f.__globals__)
    setter = types.FunctionType(codes[1], f.__globals__)
    detter = types.FunctionType(codes[2], f.__globals__)
    return property(getter, setter, detter, f.__doc__)

>>> class X:
    @dec
    def f():
        def g(*args):
            print('get', args)
        def h(*args):
            print('set', args)
        def j(*args):
            print('del', args)


>>> X().f
get (<__main__.X object at 0x02DFD870>,)
>>> X().f = 1
set (<__main__.X object at 0x02E13750>, 1)
>>> del X().f
del (<__main__.X object at 0x02DFD870>,)
```

I am interested in your thoughts.

But maybe it is even better to use a class decorator

```
@dec
class attribute: 
     # ... functions
```

Or maybe also the with statement:

```
with makeProperty:
     # ... functions
```

Comment: I really love it! I'm pretty new to working with code objects, so I wasn't familiar with co_consts. It's really great to know we can access code objects inside other code objects without executing the function. I think a class-like declaration would be nicer, but the `class` keyword may be a little bit confusing. If Python had a keyword `property` it would have been great :) As I said before, it's just a proof-of-concept.. not sure if and how I'm going to use it.. so for now it doesn't really matter if it's a `class` or a `def`  for defining properties.. but it definitely is nicer!

Comment: By the way, I improved your code a little bit by allowing the change of order of the get/set/delete methods. Your implementation requires the order to be get, then set and then delete, and it doesn't allow the user to omit one of them. I made it more flexible by looking at the code's name (i.e. `code.co_name`), looking for 'getter', 'setter' and 'deleter' (I assume naming convention here, it will make it easier to understand), and generating a dictionary of those names and `FunctionType` objects, similar to my original implementation in my main post.

Comment: It would be great i you linked to the code/results here, once it is possible. :)

Comment: I edited my question with my new implementation, based on your answer.